# Efficient generation of a Gabriel graph?

Tags: python, networkx

A [Gabriel Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_graph) is a set of vertices such that two vertices i and j are linked if there are no vertices in the disk of diameter (i,j).

I want to generate Gabriel graphs with a lot of vertices. Nevertheless, for 1000 vertices, the time needed to create such a graph is quite long, and I need more than 1000 vertices.

My idea was this one:

```
def dist(I,J):
    return math.sqrt( (I[0]-J[0])**2 + (I[1]-J[1])**2 )
G=nx.empty_graph(N) #empty graph
I=[(random.random(),random.random()) for i in range(0,N)] #nodes positions
for i in range(0,N-1):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        xm=0.5*(I[i][0] + I[j][0]) #M is the center of i and j
        ym=0.5*(I[i][1] + I[j][1])
        M=(xm,ym)
        d=min(dist(M,I[i]),dist(M,I[j])) #d is the half-distance between i and j
        possibilites=[k for k in range(0,N) if xm-d<I[k][0]<xm+d and ym-d<I[k][1]<ym+d] #we are only looking around the point M
        inter=[k for k in possibilites if dist(I[k],M)<d]
        if len(inter)==0:
            G.add_edge(i,j)
```

Do you have a better idea to generate this graph?

Comment: Interesting problem.  Your algorithm is O(N^2), so it won't behave well for large populations.  I feel like there will be a way to do it more quickly.  Here's a paper that might give a hint: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7879823/

Comment: You should edit your question to include a description of what a Gabriel graph is.

Comment: Thanks, I just did it. Another idea that came to my mind is that I should actually look at points under a distance D_N, which would be the expected maximum length of the existing links, at fixed N. I just have to find a good superior bound for D_N.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the current implementation is O(N^3)?

Comment: Yes, it is O(N^3), and not O(N^2).

Comment: Also, a node is always connected to its nearest neighbour. It may or may not be connected to neighbours further away (and probability to do so declines with distance). I feel like there should be a way to leverage a nearest neighbour data structure (KD-tree) for a more efficient implementation. At least the average running time should go down.

Comment: The other approach that I was thinking about goes like this: 1) induce the densest possible spatially embedded, planar graph on the set of vertices. 2) filter the edges. No idea how to do 1) though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my implementation (which is probably not hugely efficient and has some room for improvement, but gets done in about 10s on my macbook for a dataset of around 300 points). The implementation is less efficient but you can calculate cooler neighbourhoods with it also. I implemented the gamma-Observable Neighbour Graph[1] and when gamma=0.5, you get the Gabriel Graph. Hope this is useful:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from scipy.spatial.distance import  pdist, squareform
import bisect

def get_gong(df, y=0.5):
    # df is a pandas dataframe who has x and y as columns
    # y is the gamma parameter 
    graph = nx.DiGraph() 
    graph.add_nodes_from(df.iterrows())
    dists = pdist(df[['x','y']]) 
    dists = squareform(dists)
    y_dists = (1-y)*dists

    for node_a, row_a in df.iterrows():
        node_a_coord = list(row_a[:2]) # O(dn)
        dist_idx = np.argsort(dists[node_a]) # O(nlog n)
        for node_b in dist_idx:
            if node_a == node_b:
                continue

            node_b_coord = list(df.loc[node_b, ['x','y']])

            d_i = y_dists[node_a][node_b]
            first_greater = bisect.bisect_left(dists[node_a][dist_idx], d_i)

            b_is_GONG = True

            for node_j in dist_idx[:first_greater]:
                if node_a == node_j:
                    continue

                d_j = y_dists[node_a][node_j]

                if d_j < d_i:
                    b_is_GONG = False
                    break # node_j could be a GONG

            if b_is_GONG:
                graph.add_edge(node_a, node_b, weight = dists[node_a][node_b])
    return graph
```

[1] - M. Aupetit, P. Couturier, and P. Massotte. γ -observable neighbours
for vector quantization. Neural networks, 15(8):1017–1027, 2002.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer stub as my simulations will be finished in a second and then I need to get back to work. ;-)

According to Lemma 1 [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1538-4632.1980.tb00031.x)

> The Gabriel graph on a vertex set V is a subgraph of the Delaunay
>   triangulation for V. Furthermore, the edge AB of the Delaunay
>   triangulation is an edge of the Gabriel graph iff the straight line
>   joining A to B intersects the boundary line segment common to the
>   Thiessen polygons for A and B at a point other than the endpoints of
>   that boundary line segment.

A Delaunay triangulation can be computed in O(n log n) time.
There is a Delaunay triangulation in `scipy.spatial`. You can then filter the edges using the cited criterion by 1) computing the Voronoi diagram (also in `scipy.spatial`), and 2) asserting that edge end points are not in set of Voronoi points.

Comment: Thiessen polygons make up a Voronoi diagram.